# Plot of the set complex numbers

Tags: plotting, complex

I want to show this set (eigenvalues of my matrix):

```
WidmoA = {5.105341593663788`, -0.8165082595755606` + 0.30860875257798326` I,
  -0.8165082595755606` - 0.30860875257798326` I, 0.8354028776078447`, 
  -0.3077279521205112`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`, 0.`}
```

on the complex plane.

I use this:

```
ListPlot[(Tooltip[{Re[#1], Im[#1]}] &) /@ WidmoA, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

but I have a problem: the first element is not on the plot, the same for `0.8354028776078447`. The plot is small and limited to the rest of the values:

[image]

What should I do if I want to show all elements on the plot?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the option `PlotRange -> All`:

```
ListPlot[(Tooltip[{Re[#1], Im[#1]}] &) /@ WidmoA, AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> All]
```

Which will result in this:

[image: Plot result]

Comment: Can you add the relevant plot to show really what is going on ?